# Trying to get Graphics.py for idle 3.4

Tags: permissions, python, idle

So, I have to do a project for school using a graphics window and I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, but whenever I go to get the graphics.py file and save it in the correct directory (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages) but it says that it failed and that I have insufficient permissions. Someone suggested that I do a chmod for the directory but when I looked it up I was pretty confused. I am new to Ubuntu and have a very basic knowledge of how it works and Terminal, but I am willing to learn. Also, for future reference, if anyone has a link for beginner Ubuntu users, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to save the `graphics.py` in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`, it is easier if you do

make a folder for your project `myproject` and save the `graphics.py` in that folder and then make another python module `<name it>.py` and inside it do

```
import graphics
```

or

```
from graphics import <method name>
```

or you can put your `graphics.py` file inside

```
.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

this won't require administrative privilages and work for `idle3.4`

Comment: I tried what you said, and for having it in my myproject file, it came up with the error

"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/austinhwells/Documents/My Graphics Project/Initials.py", line 1, in <module>
    import graphics
ImportError: No module named 'graphics'"

...same thing for "from graphics import *"

and then when I tried to put it in the site-packages directory, it still denied me the permission...

Comment: had you put the graphics.py in the same directory `/home/austinhwells/Documents/My Graphics Project/`?

Comment: to put the file in site packages you don't need permissions.

Comment: you should have a blank file called`__init__.py`  file to make a folder a module and it will work.

Comment: make a `__init__.py` inside the `My Graphics Project`